# Getting an internal error trying to export from Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to fix some BQ tables and the only way seems to be exporting them, fixing locally and reuploading. But all my export attempts fail miserably. Below is just one example. I am using command line `bq`.

```
bq extract --compression=GZIP --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON test.US_2015_05 gs://???/us-2015-05--*.gz
BigQuery error in extract operation: Error processing job '???:bqjob_r1dbda9e5_00000150b2e288eb_1': An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
```

If I get rid of the wildcard from the URI, I get a different error.

```
'???:bqjob_r3e0f4cf0_00000150b2e6daf6_1': Table gs://???/us-2015-05.json too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a * to shard export.
```

Furthermore, I can't use default CSV export because my table features REPEATED fields. So it must be JSON (compressed or not).

Any ideas?

[EDIT] I get the very same internal error if I try to export from the web UI.

Comment: What makes yo feel that you cannot fix your tables within BQ? Any details? It might be more optimal to address original issue (if it exists) vs. having trouble with workaround option

Comment: Well, imagine a really complex hierarchical structure in a table 170GB big and you suddenly realize a field 4 levels deep is missing. How would you address this given an additional table with some sort of key/value data? The goal is to preserve the structure of original table (no flattening) with a new field added. If you think you have a solution, I would be happy to post a separate question giving you an opportunity to answer there. I believe it's a common BQ issue that everybody would benefit from.

Comment: I think we should try. 170GB is really nothing for BQ as well as 4 levels should be Ok. But might depend on actual case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "internal error" is a bug in our cross-region enforcement: one of the Europe regions is missing in our error map and you happened to stumble in to it. Sorry for the inconvenience and we'll get this fixed soon.

Comment: What's bothering me the most is that I stumbled upon a solution purely by accident. I figured I'd try something silly - and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of fiddling back and forth the solution is incredibly simple and yet totally unaligned with the vanilla "internal error".

The bucket I tried to export to was in EU region and this seems to confuse BQ. Creating a brand new bucket in US region made it work like a charm.

Now, how's this an "internal error" is beyond me. Nevertheless, I am glad I got this to work. I hope this helps someone save up a few wasted hours.